# Connect output tensor to placeholder in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, graph, connection

If I have a graph as follows:

```
x0 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, None, None, None))
y0 = x0 + 10.0
```

And a second one as follows:

```
x1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, None, None, None))
y1 = x1 * 5.0
```

How do I connect the output of the first graph (y0) to the input placeholder of the second graph (x1)? 
In practice I don't know the inner workings of either graph.
One goal would be to be able to apply graph 2 repeatedly like so:

```
x = x_in = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, None, None, None))
x = graph1(x)
for i in range(n):
  x = graph2(x)
x_out = x
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to compute `y1 = (x0+10.0)*5.0` you can to the following:

```
x0 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, None, None, None))
y0 = x0 + 10.0
y1 = y0 * 5.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The example i've given was a simplified version of what i was actually doing. In practice i don't know what the first and second graph do, i only have input and output. I'll update the question.

Comment: It is a bit hard to help you if you don't post your exact code. If the input of `graph2` is a placeholder and you can't change that, then you need to feed to output of `graph1` as a placeholder. The way to to that would be two have two `sess.run()`, with the first you compute the output of `graph1` and with the second you feed that into `graph2` and process it.